# Do not do anything at work (Lazy)

Tags: business, france, salary

If in an office in a company (an office job in front of the computer what) well... in fact... I look at the screen of my computer, I freeze, I do nothing for... 6 hours then I I barely work 2 hours.. every day then I look at the time until the day is over, what am I risking? Because since I passed the trial period (in France), I'm immune to being fired, right?

Answer (score 4):

You could look at [this summary](https://www.oecd.org/els/emp/France.pdf), which explains the formal requirements for sacking an employee (e.g. notice, the 'registered letter' requirement, etc). Also see [this longer analysis](https://ewll.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/EWLL-2018-dismissal-law-french-report.pdf) of dismissal law in France. The issue you would be interested in is point 5, definition of unfair dismissal.

> There must be real and serious grounds for a dismissal to be deemed
> fair. Grounds may be personal or economic. Dismissal on personal
> grounds (art. L. 1232-1): the employer must justify grounds that are
> valid and related to the individual in order to proceed with
> dismissal. These may include professional misconduct, incompetence,
> inaptitude [sic], etc. An employee who is declared unfit by the
> physician must be reclassified by the employer, taking into account
> his or her capacities (Articles L. 1226-2 and L. 1226-10).

There is a distinction between disciplinary and non-disciplinary misconduct, the former having three degrees (faute simple, faute grave, faute gross) and which seems to be about the concept "toxic work environment". The non-disciplinary grounds seems more clearly relevant, especially in that your conduct would negatively impact the execution of the work. But staring at a screen does not itself constitute a firing offense, the failure to perform work is where the problem comes from. Yes, if you don't do the work, you can be fired for not doing the work.

Answer (score 1):

The labour laws in France are outlined here

> [Employment termination law and legislation in France](https://cms.law/en/int/expert-guides/cms-expert-guide-to-dismissals/france)
>
> **1.1 Reasons for dismissal**
> The employer must establish a real and serious reason to dismiss an employee.
> It may be:
>
> - a personal reason, notably a fault (disciplinary ground), **poor performance**, disablement of the employee when the employer is unable to relocate / redeploy him to another position or make reasonable adjustments to his post; or
>   . . .

So you are not immune from being fired.